# New intro section inadvertently hides words

Tags: bug, status-completed, css

A new section has been added to the front page for new users. However it hides the word *required* behind a button. You can see this section if you log out and visit the front page.

[image: example of hidden words]

For comparison, this is the Programmers section:

[image: example with words shown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

I have already made some changes that should have made this a non-issue, and have added some more to ensure consistent look and feel.

This feature is currently being A/B tested, so you may not be able to see it again for a while...

Comment: Ace. Thanks for letting me know.